# Split Array into two sets?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl

I have an array `W` of `0..N-1`

I need to split them into two sets: Say `K` and `N-K` elements.

But the condition is: `sum(N-K)` - `sum(K)` should be maximum.

**How do I approach this?**

I tried doing this:
Sort the array - `std::sort(W,W+N)`, and then:

```
for(int i=0; i<K; ++i) less+=W[i];
for(int i=K; i<N; ++i) more+=W[i];
```

And then `more-less`

But I don't think this is the optimum way, or it may even be wrong for some of the cases.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

We have to choose `K` elements from `W` such that difference between`sum(k elements)`  and `sum(remaining elements)` is maximum.

Comment: Are those `K` (and, therefore `N-K`) elements contiguous or can be any elements of the array?

Comment: Any elements of the array :)

Comment: `sum(N-K) - sum(K)` should be maximum?

Comment: Also, are those elements all non-negative or can be negative as well?

Comment: Non-negative elements only.

Comment: There are no negative elements then sort them and only use the last element in the second set and all the other elements in the first set. Will give `maximum` result. Complexity for sorting `O(nlogn)`

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: Both. Using `stdio.h` which essentially is a C header and `<algorithm>`which is C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: Note that in your posted question, you seem to be expecting sort to sort from high-to-low.  Both `std::sort` and `std::nth_element` put the low elements first.  I have replaced `K` with `(N-K)` in the answer below to correct that.*

*Edit after UPDATE*: Do the below twice, once for `K` and once for `(N-K)`.  Choose the optimal answer.

More optimal than `std::sort` would be [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) for your purposes.

```
std::nth_element( W, W+(N-K), W+N );
```

Your use of `std::sort` will use O(n log n) complexity to order all the elements within both your sets, which you don't need.

`std::nth_element` will use O(n) complexity to *partition* without completely sorting.

*Note: your for loops may also be replaced with [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)*

```
less = std::accumulate( W, W+(N-K), 0 );
more = std::accumulate( W+(N-K), W+N, 0 );
```

Comment: This is the best approach here. Please extend your answer by explaining how exactly can this function be used here and please don't forget to mention nth_element is linear and  sort is `O(n*log(n))`

Comment: Looking through the link. Thanks... Will tell if it is helpful.

Comment: Yes, please extend your answer.

Comment: Use max heap to do it in O(n log k) time.

Comment: @user2256798 `std::accumulate` is valid C++03 and C++11.  See the link I provided.

Comment: DrewDormann please check the comments on @quetzalcoatl's answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann - Also, just sorting in reverse doesn't always give the correct answer. If `W = {8,4,5,2,10}` and `k=2` it'll separate them into {10,8} and {2,4,5} where `more-less` is `7` but it should be {10,8,5} and {2,4} where `more-less` is `17`.

Comment: @user2256798 You changed `K` to `3` in that example.  Are you saying that `K` can be any value?

Comment: No, he is freely swapping 'Sum(N-K)-Sum(K)' and 'Sum(K)-Sum(N-K)'. See his comment under my post. He provided a case of N=5, K=3 and a solution of N-K:"8,9" K="10,12,13" which he says it yields a ... 18. Certainly, (10+12+13) - (8+9) is 18, but that's not E(N-K)-E(K)

Comment: Ah.  After an hour, it's now a different question.  :)

Comment: I guess I didn't explain the question properly - please check update.

Comment: @user2256798: FYI: your `more-less` attempt is still valid for this case if you just adjust it a little: when N-K is lower than K then swap the numbers. So when N is 5 and K is 3 you'd end up with set-of-2 and set-of-three -- just swap the lengths (all in all you are free to swap the left-right sets, right?). If you always put the highest numbers to the bigger set, and lower number to the lower set, and if you always subtract sum-of-bigger minus sum-of-smaller than certainly you'd get the same result. Of course Drew's solution is still better in speed as it elimnates sorting.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to upvote, but you are **AWESOME** @DrewDormann Your update works well for all of my test cases. Thank you. You are the best.

Answer (score 2):

You are to split the set of elements into two distinctive nonoverlapping subsets A and B. You want the sum(A)-sum(B) be as high as possible.

Therefore, you want the sum(A) be as high as possible and sum(B) as low as possible.

Therefore, the set 'A' should contain as high elements as possible
and the set 'B' should contain as low elements as possible

By sorting the input set by element's value, and by assigning 'lowest elements' to B and 'highest elements' to A, you are guaranteed that the sum(A)-sum(B) will be max possible.

I do not see any cases where your approach would be wrong.

As to the 'being optimal' things, I did not analyze it at all. Drew's note seems quite probable.

Comment: `N=5` and `k=3` with `W={8,9,10,12,13}`, here `more-less` gives `-2`

Comment: Maybe I have so IQ drop today, but the -2 seems for me to be the only correct answer for this setup. "Left set", N-k, gives you 2 elements. "Right set", K, is 3 elements. I do not see how can you take 2 elements out of "8,9,10,12,13" to get higher result than -2! The highest possible result is (13+12)-(10+9+8) = -2. Exchange 13 for something else, or exchange 12 for something else, and the reaction will be that "left" will drop and "right" will rise, hence the result will be lower than -2, so -2 is the highest possible outcome..

Comment: If i partition 8,9,10,12,13 into 8,9 and 10,12,13 it'll give me 18.

Comment: @user2256798 so it seems you really want do maximize `abs(sum(N-K)-sum(k))`. In this case, just try to maximize both `sum(N-K)-sum(K)` and `sum(K)-sum(N-K)` and see which one is higher.

Comment: Not necessarily @Henrik - `abs(sum(N-K)-sum(K))` would give me 2 but I need MAXIMUM `sum(N-K) - sum(k)` which should be 18 for `W = 8,9,10,12,13` and `N=5, K=3`.

Comment: You are said to use N=5 and K=3, and you are said to calculate sum([**N-K**]) minus sum([**K**]). What you are now describing is when you calculate sum([**K**])-sum(**[N-K]**). Please note: N-K is 2, K is 3. So the "Left side" MUST have 2 elements, and the "Right side" must have three elements. Here with "18" you are trying to provide a solution of Sum(#3)-Sum(#2) which does not match the required Sum(#2)-Sum(#3).

Comment: @user2256798: If the order of N-K and K subsets is not important in the difference and if you want to get "the greatest absolute difference between the totals of two sets", then update your post accordingly. The greatest absolute difference between two totals is like `max( sum(N-K)-sum(K); sum(K)-sum(N-K) )` and it is different than just `sum(N-K)-sum(K)`

Comment: @user2256798 Congrats on the [reputation bump](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `max heap`. `O(n + n log k)` time

Make a max heap of size `k`. We have find the lowest `k` elements of the array. The `root` of heap will be the highest element in the heap. `Make a heap of first k elements`.

Now iterate through the array. Compare the array element with the `root` of max heap. If it is smaller than root then replace it and heapify the heap again. This will take O(n log k) time.
Find the sum of elements of heap.

Now you can find the sum of rest of the elements of array and get the difference. (`O(n)`) time

Total time `O(n + n log k)`

EDIT: Perhaps you can find the sum of all elements of array while traversing it for heap. This will save `O(n)` time and it can be solved in `O(n log k)`